# Manipulating Dataframe column value with a scalar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to divide the values of a column in a dataframe by an integer. I noticed that the csv file I am working on contains mostly integer values, but there are some string values. When I try to divide a whole column by an intger, it gives me an error since not all values in the column is an integer.

My question is, is there a way to bypass this?
Thanks

Comment: convert the column to numeric with `pd.to_numeric(df['your_col'], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use apply

```
df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x if type(x) == str else x/scalar_value)
```